# @SessionScoped managed bean recreated when exception is handled by PrimeExceptionHandler

Tags: jsf, primefaces, session-scope, exceptionhandler

I have a Session Scoped Bean:

```
@SessionScoped
public class UserSession {
    User user;
}
```

During my LoginView, I throw a SecurityException:

```
throw new java.lang.SecurityException("You need to login!");
```

Which will be redirected by the `web.xml` to `SelectUserBean`

Now here is the strange thing which I really do not understand: Before I throw the `SecurityException`, the `UserSession` has id `UserSession@123456` and user `Foo`. Now in the `SelectUserBean` the `UserSession` has a new id and the user is `null`.

in my `faces-config` I had Primefaces exception handling:

```
<el-resolver>       
  org.primefaces.application.exceptionhandler.PrimeExceptionHandlerELResolver
</el-resolver>
```

and

```
<factory>
    <exception-handler-factory>
       org.primefaces.application.exceptionhandler.PrimeExceptionHandlerFactory
    </exception-handler-factory>
</factory>
```

after removing, it works as expected. any ideas on this?

Why does this happen? I thought since it is a SessionScoped bean it must be the same value.

Answer (score 0):

Something in the chain created a new session, *ergo* you got a new session bean.